# How to get barcode number value using barcode plugins in Outsystems?

Tags: barcode-scanner, outsystems

Question: How to get barcode number value in Barcode Plugins of Outsystems! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the Component [page](https://www.outsystems.com/forge/Component_Details.aspx?ProjectId=1403):

> How to use this plugin?
>
> **Use ScanBarcode client action** in order to open the camera and start
>   the scanning session. If a barcode/qr code is successfully scanned,
>   **the result will be available on the Output Parameter ScanResult**. The
>   usage of front or back camera can be defined through the Settings
>   parameter, setting Camera to either “front” or “back”. Flash can also
>   be enabled or disabled and if the sight line should be drawn on the
>   screen.

You can find more information here:

[Supported Formats](https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/22388/Supported+Barcode+Formats/)
[Example](https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/33919/sample-simple-code-for-barcode-scanner-for-reference-thank-you/)